# Check the Database of a typo3-Website

Tags: database, typo3

it might be a strange question, but does anybody know how to
check the **name of the database** which is used for a **typo3** website?

Because I need this DB but I can't remember its name and I have got a lot DBs.

Thanks if Somebody knows the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log into the install tool, via url (/typo3/install) or Backend Module.
Depending on TYPO3 Version you will find it in different places there.

In latest version you will see the information directly after accessing the install tool.

Answer (score 2):

Log into the install tool, either under `typo3/install`, or via the menu in the backend when logged in as admin.

Go to "all configuration", and check the settings under `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['DB']` - everything database related is listed there.

Answer (score 2):

**TYPO3 7 LTS**

Open the Install Tool of your TYPO3 installation with the following link (only a example): `http://example.com/typo3/install`. Make sure your Install Tool is enabled with the file `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` on the folder `typo3conf`.

After login to the Install Tool you can see the database information. The informations are available on "All configuration" too. Here you can find the database area `Database [DB]`. The name of the used database you can find on `[DB][database]`.

Answer (score 0):

As nobody mentioned it yet:

If you have file access you can directly view the file `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` (`typo3conf/localconf.php` for TYPO3 before version 6.x).

All configurations from the install tool are saved there. Just search for `database`.

Comment: It could be that a value in LocalConfiguration.php is later overriden in AdditionalConfiguration.php and though not relevant. The install tool shows the value that is loaded in the end, so it is more reliable to have a look there.